# Codeigniter: 500: Internal Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hello I'am Using Codeigniter it works fine on my environment. but when i upload it, it says **500: Internal Error**

This is my .htaccess

```html
# Customized error messages.

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php


# Set the default handler.

DirectoryIndex index.php


# Various rewrite rules.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

> [Thu Nov 17 21:33:56 2016] [error] [client 120.29.125.182] SoftException in Application.cpp:313: File "/home2/choco/public_html/speedgaragedoor.com/speedgaragedoor/index.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://speedgaragedoor.com/

this is the website http://speedgaragedoor.com/speedgaragedoor/

Comment: HTTP 500 is a generic error message. When you see it your first step should always be to check your logs. They should contain more specific messages that will reveal the cause of the problem.

Comment: Just a side question: Did you intend for your CI application to be installed under speedgaragedoor folder? There is No index.xxx in your document root so we can all see your document root files.

Comment: Try renaming your .htaccess file to take it temporarily out of the picture and see if can use http://speedgaragedoor.com/speedgaragedoor/index.php... at the moment it dont work... Also that note regarding the permissions. Can you set the index.php to 644? Hostgator might be fussy over those.

Comment: Did you click on the "How Do I Fix It" link on the hostgator page that you land on?

Comment: i change permission to 644 but still 500: Internal Error. but when i delete the index.php. it is ok

Comment: when i create empty index.php : 500: Internal Error again

Answer (score 0):

you should be active mod_rewrite on apache

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

then you should be restart apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

if this operation can't solve your problem  you check the codeigniter config 
go to application->config folder and check config file
replace this codes

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/xxx';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

and

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and change the .httacess file with this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```